Is "Gita" a name given to scripture that meets some criteria?
How many Gitas are there?
this post says there are more than 100 Gitas.
is "Vyadha Gita"
Wiki:

The Vyadha Gita (meaning, songs of a butcher) is a part of the epic Mahabharata and consists of the teachings imparted by a vyadha (butcher) to a sannyasin (monk). It occurs in the Vana Parva section of Mahabharata and is told to Yudhishthira, a Pandava by sage Markandeya.[1]

considered to be an important Gita?
